# Behavior of a periodic function

Tags: derivatives, periodic-functions

Can a periodic function satisfy $f''(x)f(x)>0, x\in \mathbb{R}$

My intuition says no. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: This condition forces all critical points to be either all maximums or all minimums.

Comment: Must $f$ be defined on all $\mathbb R$? Because... $f(x) = \tan x$ :)

Comment: @kennytm It says $>0$. But $\tan(0)=0$.

Comment: @Nathanson Ok $\sec^2 x$ then.

Comment: $sec^2(x)$ seems to be good. EDIT: After a Wolfram alpha inspection $sec^2(x)$ is not good. We have some 0 values...

Comment: @prometheus21: Even if $\sec^2$ were good, it is not defined on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: True. In any way $sec^2(x)$ is not good. I think any solutions should be concentrated on a proof of non-existence.

Comment: One could try taking cases such as when $f(x)>0$, what happens.. and then try for a contradiction in each case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to prove that $\forall x\in\Bbb R(f''(x)f(x)>0) \implies f$ is not periodic.

From $f''(x)f(x)>0$ we can see that neither $f$ nor $f''$ can be $0$ at any point. Because $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous, and so it can never pass $0$ and must therefore be either positive everywhere or negative everywhere. $f''$ must have the same sign as $f$ everywhere.

Without loss of generality, assume that $f''$ and $f$ are always positive. So, because $f''$ is always positive, $f'$ is strictly increasing. If $f'$ is always negative, $f$ is strictly decreasing and $f(x)=f(x+p)$ can't hold. If $f'$ is always positive, $f$ is strictly increasing and $f(x)=f(x+p)$ can't hold. If $f'$ passes $0$, $f$ has exactly one minimum at some $x_0$, and $f(x_0)=f(x_0+p)$ can't hold. So $f$ can not be periodic.

Comment: Basic calculus only. Nice.

Comment: @Jack: I will accept your edit but make the slight modification of expanding the acronym. Also, thank you.